# Laravel migration MySQL foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I have two tables:

Users (id, name)

Events (id, name, date, user_created_id, user_updated_id (etc...)

How can I make a relationship between the two ids of the Events table with the user id?

```
user_created_id -> users.id
user_updated_id -> users.id
```

**UPDATE**

```
$table->integer('user_created_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('user_updated_id')->nullable();

$table->foreign('user_created_id')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->foreign('user_updated_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: You ask about what to do in database or how to write the relation code?

Comment: I know how to do with Laravel Eloquent, but I do not know how to do in database with laravel migration.

Comment: Read @nakov answer. It's what you need

Comment: I had tried that before posting

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: Share your migration file to check what's wrong

Comment: Updated first post, thanks

Comment: You forgot some code after **references**. Read @nakov answer carefully

Comment: Sorry, was copy-paste problem, I update know the post with the correct one.

Comment: I notes nullable() in your migration.  Remove it and try

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 `nullable()` is not a problem at all.

Comment: I know @nakov. Just to check he didn't use an older version of laravel

Comment: I have the last Laravel version, 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how to make a foreign key for those two columns, then here:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_created_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_updated_id');

$table->foreign('user_created_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('user_updated_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

If your `id` column on the `users` table is `bigIncrements` then replace the `unsignedInteger` with `unsignedBigInteger`

Comment: The problem might be because you have different types, so check my comment bellow the code. What type of column is the `id` in the `users` table. Is it `increments` or `bigIncrements`?

Comment: And if you compare it with mine it is completely different. You are not telling it to which table it references the id. So please use the code above from me.

Comment: Sorry, was copy-paste problem, I update know the post with the correct one.

Comment: And can you please show me how is your `id` on the `users` table defined? is it `$table->increments('id');`?

Comment: Yes, `$table->increments('id');`

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. Are you certain that the error comes out of this migrations? Have you created other migrations and you try to run them all at once? 
Do you have tried another foreign key if it works? Does your `users` table exists before you try to create the `events` table?

Comment: Thanks for all, problem solved with this.
Laravel when it is an unsigned field gives it a length of 10 and if not 11. I have also set it unsigned to user_updated_id and now works.
`$table->integer('user_created_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('user_updated_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

$table->foreign('user_created_id')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->foreign('user_updated_id')->references('id')->on('users');`

Comment: pretty much with what I have given you, except of the `nullable` on the `update_id`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Event` model, you can define two relationships:

```php
public function user_created(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_created_id');
}

public function user_updated(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_updated_id');
}
```

In your `User` model, you can also define the reverse relationships:

```php
public function created_events(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'user_created_id');
}

public function updated_events(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'user_updated_id');
}
```

With these relationshops, you can call `$event->user_created` to retrieve the `App\User` linked to the `user_created_id` (same for the `updated` version).

With a `App\User` instance, you can call `$user->created_events` to get a collection of `App\Event` (again, it's the same with `$user->updated_events`).